# RabbitMQ direct exchange, with routing key and no queues or subscribers, is this ok for performance?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an exchange that's going to receive roughly 50 messages per second. These messages have a unique identifier which relates to each unit in the field. This unique identifier will be the routing key.  Every now and again we need to debug or analyse a unit. At that point in time we will spin up a queue, with the correct routing key, and bind it to the exchange. This way, that queue will start receiving the messages for that unit and any consumers monitoring that queue, will then receive the messages.

What this does mean is that 99% of the time, the exchange will have no queues and no routing key.  Then, every now and again a queue and routing key will be created and subscribe.

It feels kind of wasteful to be sending 50 messages per second at an exchange, when its just going to immediately discard them.  That said, it feels like this how RabbitMQ exchanges are supposed to be used.  I guess from a developer perspective i feel like this is wasteful but I also think my understanding of rabbit says that this is the correct way to do.

Is there any overhead to doing this? Any performance concerns I should have?  or maybe I am approaching this entirely wrong?

I did try to search before asking but nothing really describes a scenario where an exchange has no queue or routing key, but is still receiving messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically how RabbitMQ works, as you have described. The broker is not responsible for how often and how many events you decide to publish. It will nonetheless protect from too much pressure. It has a credit based flow control mechanism. [RabbitMQ flow control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/flow-control.html).

RabbitMQ has different ways in which unroutable messages can be handled.[Unroutable Message Handling](https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#unroutable) [How to deal with unroutable messages](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/3/12/how-to-deal-with-unroutable-messages-rabbitmq-publishing-part-3)

To sum up a bit the information you will find on those links:

If the publisher does not set the message as mandatory, it will either be discarded or republished to a different alternate exchange that you can configure. This only makes sense if you want to persist all unroutable messages regardless of the source in a single queue, that you can handle later.

If the publisher sets the message as mandatory, the message will be returned to the publisher and the publisher can have a returned message handler setup in order to handle those events.

These strategies in addition to the flow control mechanism, also assure RabbitMQ reliability and protection.

In your situation if you want to limit the messages from producer even more, you need to create a mechanism, as an example, so the producer will not start publishing only when a consumer becomes active. So basically the consumer process will communicate the producer process that it is active and it can start publishing. But from my experience I don't think it's worth the overhead, at least at first, because 50 messages per seconds isn't much. You can monitor the RabbitMQ server and check how is the resource consumption to check if you need to optimize, at first. Optimization is best done with metrics and understanding.

Comment: Also, the OP might consider using a temporary queue ([example here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html)) which is created and goes away once the consumer exits.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i figured but i was struggling to find information to back up my theories.    As the above comment suggests, i will be using temporary queues to manage this. The only times messages won't be discarded is when there's a queue and consumer with the correct routing key available.  Which is exactly what i want.

thanks again.